# What is the effect of the new operator in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, new-operator

I am pretty new to spring. I have a doubt on the `new` operator which is inside the spring registered class.

I created a class called points.

```
public class Points { // methods and variables}
```

I created another class called circle.

```
public class Circle { Points p=new Points(); }
```

And I registered Circle in spring container like below.

```
<bean id="circle" class="com.springeg.eg.Circle" />
```

Now whether spring will handle only the object life cycle of Circle class or it will handle `Circle` and `Points` class `p` object too.

what is the impact of new operator inside a spring registered class?

Comment: A field in a spring managed bean is not a spring managed bean (unless you made it so and injected it)

Comment: i didnt understand... you are saying that object p will not handled by spring right

Comment: yes `p` is not "handled" by spring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `new` explicitly instead of injecting the `Points` instance, you're not allowing Spring to manage it.
Your `Circle` instance will be managed by Spring, but the `Points` instance inside is just a plain java object, with no fancy management around it.

Comment: In that case if i registered Points in spring.xml and if i create a new object the what will the impact

Comment: If you're explicitly calling `new`, it doesn't matter if you registered `Points` or not - it's outside of Spring's reach.